# How convert int8_t array into integer value in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, int, valueconverter, uint8t

I have the following array :

```
static const int8_t ARRAY[8] = {0x18, 0xB8, 0xCE, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
```

and I need to get an integer value. For this `ARRAY` final `int` value is `13547544`, because the bytes in the array, followed by in the opposite order `little-endian`.

Example `0xCEB818 = 13547544`

How can I do this? 
Can have ready standard solutions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything? you might get more help if you demonstrate you've tried "something" or researched your problem before asking for a "ready standard solution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the host platform is little-endian, you can just point a 64-bit integer pointer at the array and the machine will read the array correctly.

```
static const int8_t ARRAY[8] = {0x18, 0xB8, 0xCE, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0};
uint64_t *value = (uint64_t *)&ARRAY;

NSLog(@"%llu", *value); // outputs 13547544
```

Comment: Thank you, incredibly simple!